# Renaming formelements in a particular range with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've multiple autogenerated forms on a page. They are named in a particular manner like:

form-0-weight, form-1-weight, form-2-weight etc.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input id="id_form-0-weight" type="text" name="form-0-weight">
    <a class="deleteIngredient" href="">x</a>
  </li>
  <li>
   ....more forms
  </li>
</ul>
```

The user can add and delete forms. If a form get's deleted, the remaining ones should be renamed to stay in order. e.g. "form-1-weight" gets deleted >> "form-2-weight" will be renamed to "form-1-weight".
The total number of forms is stored in a hidden field named TOTAL_FORMS.

I'm trying to achieve this with a simple for loop.
The problem is that all the forms after the deleted one get the same name.
e.g. If I delete form-2-weight, all the following forms get the name form-2-weight instead of 2, 3, 4 etc.

```
$(".deleteIngredient").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var delete = $(this).closest('li');

    name = delete.children('input').attr("name");
    count = name.replace(prefix,'');
    count = name.replace("-weight",'');
    var formCount = parseInt($("#TOTAL_FORMS").val())-1;
    delete.remove();

    for (var i = parseInt(count); i<=formCount; i++){
        var newName = "form-"+i+"-weight";
        $("#id_form-"+(i+1)+"-weight").attr("name",newName);
    }
});
```

I suppose it has something to do with how I select the elements inside the loop because when I use just the variable "i" instead of "newName" it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not initializing i properly.
This happens because "count" doesn't contain a string that can be parsed into an integer under the conditions of parseInt, I suggest you look here:
[w3Schools/parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

> Note: If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.

When you assign a string to "count" you're actually inserting the string "form-i" into the variable.

What you should do is this:

```
count = name.replace(prefix,'');
count = count.replace("-weight",'');
```

You should also rename your "delete" variable to "form" or any other descriptive name, as delete is a reserved word in javascript and also an action so it doesn't really suit as a name for an object.
Don't forget to change the id attribute of the item so it'll fit the new name.

As a note, you should probably consider following through some tutorial on Javascript or jQuery, [Tuts+ learn jQuery in 30 days](https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/) is one i'd recommend.

Answer (score 0):

My first impulse is just to solve this a different way.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn698/)

```
var $ul = $('ul');

// Add a new ingredient to the end of the list
function addIngredient() {
    var $currentIngredients = $ul.children();
    var n = $currentIngredients.length;
    var $ingredient = $('<li>', {
        html: '<input type="text" /> <a href="#" class="delete-ingredient">x</a>'
    });

    $ul.append($ingredient);
    renameIngredientElements();
}

// Rename all ingredients according to their order
function renameIngredientElements() {
    $ul.children().each(function (i, ingredient) {
        var $ingredient = $(ingredient);
        var $input = $ingredient.find('input');
        var name = 'form-' + i + '-weight';

        $input
            .attr('id', 'id_' + name)
            .attr('name', name);
    });
}

// Delete an ingredient
function deleteIngredient($ingredient) {
    $ingredient.remove();
    renameIngredientElements();
}

// Bind events
$('.add-ingredient').on('click', addIngredient);

$ul.on('click', '.delete-ingredient', function (event) {
    var $ingredient = $(event.currentTarget).closest('li');
    deleteIngredient($ingredient);

    event.preventDefault();
});
```

As to why your particular code is breaking, it looks like *user2421955* just beat me to it.